# How can i validate an nsstring is valid url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Want to check like
Valid URL's are:

```
www.mywebsite.com
http://www.mywebsite.com
https://www.mywebsite.co.in
```

Invalid URL's are

```
wwww.mywebsite.com
htt://www.mywebsite.com
htto://www.mywebsite.com
```

I try

```
 NSString *urlRegEx =
     @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
```

This and another regex which must have to `http` or `https`, and also it is taking many "w". And only `www.mywebsite.com` is invalidate by this regex.

Search all the web but stuck here.

Comment: Just pass it to NSURL, then pick out the schema and check it?

Comment: you could try creating an NSURL from it

Comment: @trojanfoe: Don't dup it with a regex question. Regex is a poor tool here.

Comment: @nhahtdh The OP is using a regular expression so I am assuming that's what he wants to use.

Comment: @trojanfoe: When close dup, use the best question possible for the context. Here, the OP wants to know if a URL is valid or not in iOS, so it's best to use the available tool, rather than a flaky regex.

Comment: Regular expressions are available in iOS so it's appropriate.

Comment: Note that `wwww` or `ww1` can point to a valid host - you never know.

Comment: Take the highest voted answer from the dupe, not necessarily th voted correct answer

Comment: all the answer is not working what i want

Comment: Try this                                                                                              NSString *urlRegEx = @"http(s)?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?";

Comment: Remove delimiters, use double slashes where necessary. NSString * expression = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[a-zA-Z0-9./\\?:@\\-_=#]+\\.([a-zA-Z0-9./\\?:@\\-_=#])*";. It can even be contracted to NSString *pattern = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[\\w./\\?:@=#-]+\\.([\\w./\\?:@=#-])*";